# Spring boot JPA native query and pagination using countQuery

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I saw this example for native query which use `countQuery`:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1 ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}",
        countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
        nativeQuery = true)
    Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);   
 }
```

And the second example:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
     @Query(value="SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1", nativeQuery=true)
     Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
 }
```

The second example does not use `countQuery`, so what in the best practice? Can you explain ?

I tried both and both work well. What is the best practice ?

Comment: Turn on SQL logging and verify both are the same. Spring when using pagination will return the absolute count for a query, allowing the client to not only receive the number of records in the current page, but the count of records so they can figure out the number of pages as well. Think of any website you've had where they have a catalogue of products- the best tell you how many pages there are and allow you to flip to any of those pages. With JPA queries, Spring can rework the query and reuse the filters with a separate count query, but it cannot for SQL native queries

Answer (score 1):

You can omit it if it is the same as your original query.

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html#countQuery()) :

> **countQuery**
>
> Defines a special count query that shall be used for pagination queries to lookup the total number of elements for a page. **If none is configured we will derive the count query from the original
> query or countProjection() query if any**.

`countQuery` is useful when you need a different query to compute total items (this should almost never be the case though).

---

Note that `countQuery` can also be needed when you have a `Pageable` along with a non-native query, and need to fetch lazy loaded associations.

For example, let's assume your `User` entity has a lazy loaded `registrations` association :

This will not compile (query validation should fail with the below error message) :

```java
@Query(value = "select u from Users u left join fetch u.registrations where lastName = ?1")
Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
```

> org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: query specified join fetching,
> but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select
> list

This will work :

```java
@Query(value = "select u from Users u left join fetch u.registrations where lastName = ?1",
  countQuery = "select u from Users u left join fetch u.registrations where lastName = ?1")
Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
```

(Note that you could have used `@EntityGraph` in that later case, this is just to demonstrate a use case of the `countQuery` where it is required).